# How to dynamically get and use compiled module with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to dynamically get compiled module without writing it in file, is it possible to do with webpack?

For example result of webpack compilation is object

```
{"foo":"I need that info"}
```

Can I do something like

```
var compiler = webpack(config);
var result = compiler.compile()
console.log(result.foo)
```

?

Sync or async does not matter.

Comment: Why you need this? What is the use case?